# SQL command to perform division

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, sqlcommand, relational-division

I have the following tables.

```
STUDENT(ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, MAJOR)
INSTRUCTOR(ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DEPARTMENT, SALARY)
COURSE(ID, COURSE_NAME, DESCRIPTION)
COURSE_OFFERING(ID, COURSE_ID, INSTRUCTOR_ID,  SEMESTER)
GRADE(STUDENT_ID, COURSE_OFFERING_ID,  GRADE)
```

Find the names of all students who have taken every course taught by Einstein.

The sql command which I used is

```
select STUDENT_ID 
from grade where not exists
   (select grade.COURSE_OFFERING_ID from grade 
    where grade.COURSE_OFFERING_ID not in 
           (
             select course_offering.ID 
             from instructor join course_offering 
             where instructor.ID = course_offering.INSTRUCTOR_ID 
             and instructor.FIRST_NAME = 'Einstein')
           );
```

Please explain where I am making a mistake or is there any other way to perform division in SQL?

Comment: I don't see any division here?  Why are you using not exists and not in?  You should be able to use a single positive relationship instead of two negatives.

Comment: I have to find the students who have taken all the courses. So it comes under division right? When I put it in relational algebra, first I would find courses taught by Einstein and then to find students who taken all, I need to divide by first result. So I want to know how to put relational algebra division in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I think outer join is needed here, something like

```
  select STUDENT_ID, count(*) cnt
  from grade 
  left join course_offering c on COURSE_OFFERING_ID = c.ID
  left join instructor i on INSTRUCTOR_ID = i.ID and i.LAST_NAME='Einstein'
  where c.ID is NULL
  group by STUDENT_ID
  having cnt=0;
```

Comment: technically you need student names - so join STUDENT for that

Comment: This query is not returning anything.